# How I can create a Chrome extension that reads an xml or json

Tags: javascript, xml, json, google-chrome-extension

I tried to schedule a google chrome extension that I only pull one json or xml to display content from my website. But I could not do this task might say some example of code to perform this task. I will be greatly thankful

Here's an example of how to configure my manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Name",
   "description": "My WEB SITE DESCRIPTION."
   "version": "1.0",

   "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }
   "permissions": [
     "http://domain.com/"
   ]
}
```

And as I try to get a XML (if they know how I can achieve a JSON will be equally useful):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function inicial(){
         xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://domain.com/feed", false); 
         xmlhttp.send(null);
         if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
                     xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
                     var links = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("link"); 
                     alert(links);
          } else if (xmlhttp.status==404) {
               alert("XML could not be found");
          }
});
```

Greetings.

Comment: Kjhughes Hello, I just changed my post please re-read

Comment: maybe you want to try http://crossrider.com/ there are many possibilities.. i had good experience

Comment: I just need to read a remote xml or json to display information from my web sition to the extent that I want to create for other users to install

Comment: You want that info shown in your popup ? What is your popup structure/content. What is not working (i.e. what happens when you run thecode) ?

Comment: When I run my code does not run in popup on what I've read there are some restrinciones do not let me because they have changed the way to get the xml or json data but I can not come up with the solution

Comment: @FrancisGoris: It is customary to also upvote the accepted answer. Just saying... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a number of errors in the code you provide. I realize many of them might have been introduced while adapting the code for posting here and thus might not exist in the actual code. In any case, this is how you should do it from scratch:

**Extension file-structure:**

```
extension-root-directory/
                       |___manifest.json
                       |___popup.html
                       |___popup.js
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "<EXTENSION-NAME>",
    "description": "<EXTENSION-DESCRIPTION>",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "<BROWSER-ACTION-TITLE>",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "<URL-TO-XML-OR-JSON>"   // e.g. "http://domain.com/feed"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Loading...
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
var ajaxURL = "<URL-TO-XML-OR-JSON>";   // e.g. "http://domain.com/feed"
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxURL, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var data = xmlhttp.responseXML;   // or JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)
        // Do stuff with the retrieved data...
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        document.body.innerHTML("Failed to load the data !");
    }
});
```